# List comprehension on csv object

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have this code where i am trying to do list comprehension on `data` :

```
with open('data.csv') as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    data1 = [x.replace('.', '-') for x in data]
```

but for some reason `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'` How can i fix this?

data.csv has

```
MMM
ABT
ABBV
ABMD
ACN
ATVI
ADBE
AMD
AAP
AES
AMG
AFL
A
APD
AKAM
ALK
ALB
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of your data?

Comment: That's right, you cant `[].replace` - were you expecting to iterate over *strings*? The point of the CSV reader is that it gives you lists of the values for each row in the source data.

Comment: @InderjeetSingh `replace` does *not* work on `list`. The method `list.replace` does not exist.

Comment: Please provide a sample CSV file.

Comment: Why are you treating that as a CSV file? It only has a single value per line, by the look of it. Also none of the examples have the character you're proposing to replace...

Comment: @Tim I cannot add the csv file to this post. I have copied and pasted a few lines from the csv file in the question though

Comment: @jonrsharpe There are a few symbols which has those characters.`BRK.B` is one of these symbols which i want to replace

Comment: Maybe your example should include some? Do any rows have multiple values and, if not, why are you calling it CSV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` is a list of lists, so you need to iterate over the 'rows':

```
with open('test.csv') as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')

    for row in data:
        row = [col.replace('.', '-') for col in row]
```

**Edit:**
In case there is just one value per line, you dont need the csv module.

```
print ([line.replace('.', '-') for line in open('data.txt').read().splitlines()])
```

Output:

```
['MMM', 'ABT', 'ABBV', 'ABMD', 'ACN', 'ATVI', 'ADBE', 'AMD', 'AAP', 'AES', 'AMG', 'AFL', 'A', 'APD', 'AKAM', 'ALK', 'ALB']
```

Answer (score 0):

Each entry in your data is a list.

Simply apply `replace()` on the first element of each result:

```
import csv

with open('data.csv') as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    data1 = [x[0].replace('.', '-') for x in data]
```